# How to create equal height row & stack column one below other in small view?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I want to create the grid with two columns & some rows such that both rows have same height (max height). But in my case rows of unequal heights are getting created. For example, column1: row1 have less content so its height is small but if adjacent column2: row1 has more content its getting more height & thus creating unequal/unaligned columns.

The grid I want to achieve is:

For desktop screens:

[image: Desktop View]

For small screens:

[image: Mobile View]

Could you please advise me on how can I get the desired result?

Edit: I just need 2 columns & several row/container in desktop.

Comment: You could use Javascript for this. If you don't have any dynamically added content (AJAX and the like), and no hidden content for the rows you want to style (`display: none;` and the like), you could loop through your target rows, picking up the height of all of them, keeping the height of the tallest row, and then applying that to other rows. Place it all in a function, and trigger it on page load, and if the size of the window changes, or if the orientation changes, etc.

Comment: Hi @FiddlingAway,
Thanks for suggestion. Could you please share any example for this?

Comment: Please post a sample of your HTML, and the CSS you're currently using, so that I or someone else, might be able to adapt the Javascript suggestion to your specific code.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: max-content;
}

.column {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: cursive;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column" style="background-color: lightblue;">
    <p>Column 1 Content</p>
    <p>Column 1 Content</p>
    <p>Column 1 Content</p>
    <p>Column 1 Content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color: lightgreen;">
    <p>Column 2 Content</p>
    <p>Column 2 Content</p>
    <p>Column 2 Content</p>
    <p>Column 2 Content</p>
    <p>Column 2 Content</p>
    <p>Column 2 Content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color: hotpink;">
    <p>Column 3 Content</p>
    <p>Column 3 Content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color: grey;">
    <p>Column 4 Content</p>
    <p>Column 4 Content</p>
    <p>Column 4 Content</p>
    <p>Column 4 Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Comic Sans MS" as a font. Have to resist my urge to downvote 

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I need only 2 columns & several equal rows which holds some content like text & image as well.

Comment: @alex So on desktop screens, you want only 2 columns? Something else I'm missing?

Comment: @Ghost Yes! I just need 2 columns in my desktop view & they should stack on each other in mobile view. But the rows height should be uniform in desktop view (i.e. the max height). I guess they are more like containers in column not rows.